# copy a image matrix size to another matrix in OpenCV

Tags: c, opencv, image-processing

I am trying to load an image from a file as a CvMat (as mat1) and trying to create another matrix (mat2) as same size as the file being read and trying to subtract the average value of the original matrix (mat1) and trying to insert the value into the new matrix (mat2) but unfortunately I am getting an error. Can anybody tell me why? I am using C API in OpenCV. The following is the code

```
   CvMat* mat1 = cvLoadImageM(argv[2], CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED); // load an image from a file as a CvMat 

   CvMat*  mat2 = cvCreateMat(mat1->width, mat1->height, CV_32FC1); // trying to create a matrix as same width and height as the image file being loaded.

   CvScalar avg = cvAvg(mat1); // calculating the avg of all elements of matrix

   cvSubS(mat1, avg, mat2); // subtracting the average value from the original matrix and inserting the new values to matrix mat2
```

The error is

```
   OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (src1.size == dst.size && src1.channels() == dst.channels()) in cvAddS, file /home/Documents/opencv-2.4.5/modules/core/src/arithm.cpp, line 2783 terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception' what():  /homeDocuments/opencv-2.4.5/modules/core/src/arithm.cpp:2783: error: (-215) src1.size == dst.size && src1.channels() == dst.channels() in function cvAddS
```

Comment: Is your mat1.type CV_32FC1?

Comment: @William I don't know. I am just trying to load it from an image file. Do you know how can I check it's type? mat1 's values are 0 and -2

Comment: Can you try `mat1->type()` instead of `CV_32FC1`?

Comment: It's important to set the Mat types properly. Follow @JonesV hint.

Comment: @JonesV yes the error is gone but I am getting a white blank image as output. Can you tell me why?

Comment: @William yes the error is gone but I am getting a white blank image as output. Can you tell me why?

Comment: @JonesV it worked with mat1->type not type()

Comment: I wrote it in an answer so that you can validate it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't know the type of `mat1`, you can use `mat1->type` to get it.

Try to use the following:

```
CvMat*  mat2 = cvCreateMat(mat1->width, mat1->height, mat1->type); // trying to create a matrix as same width and height as the image file being loaded.
```

Comment: your first suggestion works but not your second one, it shows error

Answer (score 2):

> cvCreateMat(rows, cols)

As such would you not need

```
CvMat*  mat2 = cvCreateMat(mat1->height, mat1->width, CV_32FC1);
```

Swap the width and height props around.

The error is because you've either got the wrong width height dimension or the wrong number of channels in your target (mat2) image. I'm guessing CvScalar returns a 1 channel image. so its probably the dimensions.